# Inner Join com valores repetidos

Tags: php, mysql, join, while, inner

Bom dia!
sera que alguém pode me ajudar com uma dúvida?

eu tenho um select

```
SELECT * FROM order 
INNER JOIN kn_status ON (kn_order.n_order = kn_status.fk_order)
WHERE kn_order.fk_cliente='$id'
```

o problema é que na tabela **STATUS** o **N_ORDER** se repete varias vezes
e quando eu executo o **WHILE** ele me mostra o resultado da tabela ORDER repetido.

Comment: Seria mais válido se você mostrasse o que tem na tabela e qual o resultado esperado

Comment: Mas como voce quer trazer só 1 registro sendo que tem varias repetições dele na tabela STATUS? Voce precisa passar outro 'parâmetro' único para poder trazer uma unica linha. O seu JOIN na estrutura da tabela esta errado ao meu ver. Voce deveria ter montado a estrutura com um ID_STATUS (ÚNICO) como chave estrangeira e não numero da ordem que nem esta ai apresentado. Se possível poste a estrutura da tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Davi! Isso é um problema de estrutura. Se a coluna n_order será relacionada com coluna de outra tabela, então ela deveria ser uma coluna única (sendo o seu objetivo). 
Mas caso isso não é a restrição, ou seja, a coluna n_order pode repetir, então utilize a coluna de diferenciação de valores. Essa coluna de diferenciação é onde informa que uma linha é diferente da outra.

Boa sorte!